# Como optimizar estas llamadas al State

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Me gustaría saber como se podrían optimizar estas llamadas para no estar repitiendo la misma sentencia para refrescar el State en cada acción.

```
export const CategoriesPage = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<Category[]>([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleCreateCategory = (newCategory: CategoryCreate, file: File) => {
    createCategoryHelper(newCategory, file)
      .then(() => {
        getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories);
      })
      .finally(() => handleClose());
  };

  const handleDeleteCategory = (categoryId: Id) => {
    SwalHelper.delete().then(() => {
      deleteCategoryHelper(categoryId).then(() =>
        getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories)
      );
    });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const handleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PageTitle title="Categories" />
      <FilterBar>
        <Button type="button" background="green" onClick={handleModal}>
          + Add new
        </Button>
      </FilterBar>
      {showModal && (
        <ModalPortal onClose={handleClose}>
          <CreateCategoryForm
            createCategory={(category, file: File) => {
              handleCreateCategory(category, file);
            }}
          />
        </ModalPortal>
      )}

      <ListGrid columns={3}>
        {categories.map((category) => {
          const { id: categoryId } = category;
          return (
            <CategoryCard
              key={categoryId}
              {...category}
              onClick={() => handleDeleteCategory(categoryId)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ListGrid>
    </>
  );
};
```

1. Cuando el componente es montado, en el useEffect, se llena el State con la respuesta para crear una lista.
2. Cuando la categoria es creada, se llama al State otra vez para refrescar la lista.
3. Lo mismo al borrar, en el mismo *then*, se refresca de nuevo para hacer el update de la lista.

```
getCategoriesHelper().then(setCategories)
```

3 llamadas para hacer un update al state y actualizar la lista.

Hay alguna manera de optimizar este código y hacerlo más limpio y reusable?
Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Podrías encapsular toda la logica referente a `Categories` en un hook `useCategories`. Ese hook puede retornar funciones como `createCategory`, `deleteCategory`, y `getCategories`

Comment: habia pensado en algo parecido. muchas gracias!